# Running JS function for a second time

Tags: javascript, function, pagination

Given the following code snippet;

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    pagination();

    jQuery("#FormButton").click(function()
    {
        pagination();
    });

});

function pagination()
{
    jQuery(".pagination").myPagination({
        totalPages: 12,
        visiblePages: 3,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
        }
    });
}
```

On inital page load the pagination function is called and creates the pagination html as expected.
However, when the pagination function is called after the form button has been clicked the myPagination function is not called although the outer pagination function is. The page should not reload after the form button is clicked.
What do I need to do in order for the pagination html to be updated whenever the form button is clicked?
The number of total pages changes upon options set in a form, i.e. show 30 results per page, 60, 90 etc

Comment: I could not see reload script...

Comment: Is the form button a submit button?

Comment: would be useful if you add html code also

Comment: The button is a simple html `<button>`, not a submit. There is no actual html `<form>`, I am capturing events using jQuery. I need a way to run `myPagination` independent from an initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('.pagination').removeData("myPagination");` solved this issue.
Cleared the elements data before re-initialising the pagination to it.